# JavaScript toggle button only works on second click if display attribute is in header

Tags: javascript, css, togglebutton

I came across an interesting quirk, and was wondering if anyone could help me understand it. A simple JavaScript-driven toggle button, as below, works beautifully if the `display:none` of the toggled element is contained in-line.  However, when I move the CSS statement to the `<style>` tag in the header, or to a separate CSS file, it starts to toggle only on the second click, and from then on, it works fine, on a single-click-per-toggle basis.  Here's the JS function:

```
<script>
    function openSec(ordinal) {
        var tab_name = "sec" + ordinal;
        if (document.getElementById(tab_name).style.display == "none") {
            document.getElementById(tab_name).style.display = "table";
        } else {
            document.getElementById(tab_name).style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you could probably get away with just saying  style.display!="table" in your if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the CSS statement is in the style tag, it no longer exists as an attribute of the DOM element that is getting clicked.  The browser is still applying the style, but the DOM element no longer has that value as a style attribute.  So the first click, there is no display:none, so it adds it, then on the second click it replace it with table.

Use your browser's dev tools (or something like Firebug) to examine the initial HTML, then examine it again after the first click and I think you will see a difference.

Comment: Very interesting. I hadn't thought to examine it with dev tools, but I suspected the answer was in that direction. Thanks!